# When I read the firebase records, type error getting

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-redux

Im new at react, I try to read firebase records, but it seems likte to be error at rowHasChanged method;

typeerror: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new_raeactaive.FlatList.DataSoruce ({rowHasChanged:function rowHasChanged(r1, r2) { return r1 !==r2;}}))]

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  FlatList
} from 'react-native';
import {
  connect
} from 'react-redux';
import {
  studentListData
} from '../actions/StudentAcitions';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class Studentlist extends Component {
  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.props.studentListData();
    this.createDataSource(this.props);
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.createDataSource(nextProps);
  }
  createDataSource({
    studentsArray
  }) {
    const ds = new FlatList.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    });

    this.DataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(studentsArray);
  }
  renderRow(ogrenci) {
    return <ListItem ogrenci = {
      ogrenci
    }
    />;
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      View >
      <
      FlatList data = {
        this.props.studentsArray
      }
      renderItem = {
        this.renderRow
      }
      keyExtractor = {
        (item, index) => index.toString()
      }
      /> <
      /View>
    );}
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of createDataSource function?

Comment: I created this function (createDataSource) for set to  this.DataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(studentsArray);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlatList does not have the DataSource function ListView does. Try to change to Listview instead of FlatList. You can see ListView with DataSource in below link

https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.49/listview

**Note:** ListView is Deprecated